# Hide entire column based on Slicer selection

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, pivot-table, slicers

I have a pivot table(PivotTable1) and slicer called Team. Slicer has 4 options, what I want is, when a user selects Re-issue from slicer only then column G pops-up otherwise it should be hidden for the other three options.

Below code does not do anything when I make the Re-issue selection on the slicer. I'm not getting any errors neither the required result.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate (ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    If Target.Name <> "PivotTable1" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
       If Parent.SlicerCaches("Team").SlicerItems("Re-issue").Selected = True Then
        Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
       Else
        Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please add  more detail to your question.

Comment: @BigBen No, I'm not getting any error. It's just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does it just hit the `Exit Sub` line?  Have you added some breakpoints and tried triggering the code?

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: Check you haven't somehow disabled events - restarting excel will fix that, or put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate pane and hit enter